# How to stop node sass from removing quotes from within variables

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I have this:

```
$myicon: url("data:image/svg+xml, encoded image in here" );

.myicon:before {
    content: $myicon;
}
```

Which results in this css:

```
.myicon:before {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml, encoded image in here);
}
```

Notice that my double quotes are gone.   How can I define the variable so that the quotes do not get removed?

I've tried wrapping everything with quotes but then my css is also wrapped in quotes.

If you're wondering why I care about the quotes being there .. sometimes my svg definitions have characters like ) that mess things up .. having the css quoted prevents that sort of thing.

Comment: I think this has been fixed by now @brian-pearson :)
See your working example: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/89358f3cc3ea60faf893ab72dea6eb27